# Application item on Menu bar

Tags: application-development

I used to have an drop down on my menu bar called "Applications" but it now gone. It was alongside the "Activities" item.
Can I get it back? Thanks
Roger

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Such menu is provided by a gnome Shell extension.

1. Make sure `gnome-shell-extensions` is installed. If not, install with `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions` in the terminal or using Software.
2. Have, depending on your Ubuntu version, "Gnome Tweaks" or "Extensions" installed. If not, install with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-prefs`.
3. Turn on the extension "Applications menu" in either the Gnome Tweaks or Extensions tool (more recent Ubuntu versions).